# Java Generics - Why is new Money<Dollar>(4.0) === new Money<Franc>(4.0) equal?

Tags: java, generics, jvm, typeclass

Why is `assertNotEquals(new Money<Dollar>(4.0), new Money<Franc>(4.0));` equal?

This test fails.

I really don't understand why this assertion doesn't succeed.

Is it because assertNotEquals matches the superclass of Money?
From my understanding, those two inline instantiations should be two different types.

I think this is so when you implement this with Scala.

But I don't understand what's happening here.
Is this a JVM specific matter?
Currency.java:

```
public class Currency {

    private final String shortcut;

    public Currency(String shortcut) {
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
    }

    public String getShortcut() {
        return shortcut;
    }
}
```

Dollar.java (And similar to it Franc.java)

```
public class Dollar extends Currency {
    public Dollar() {
        super("USD");
    }
}
```

ExchangeRate.java

```
@Value // lombok
public class ExchangeRate<C extends Currency, TargetC extends Currency> {

    Double rate;

}
```

Money.java

```
@Value
public class Money<C extends Currency> {

    private final Double amount;

    public final <TargetC extends Currency> Money<TargetC> exchange(ExchangeRate<C, TargetC> rate) {
        return new Money<TargetC>(amount * rate.getRate());
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems `Money` does not implement `equals`. Why? `assertNotEquals` should not succeed.

Comment: @f1sh There is a `@Value` annotation: https://projectlombok.org/features/Value

Comment: @Tom ah, ok. Then it's obvious, the generated `equals` compares the `amount` field, and `4.0 == 4.0` is true, regardless of any generic type.

Comment: @f1sh Yes, I would think so to. I don't see a reason why Lombok should include a check for the current type of `C` in `equals`.

Comment: @Tom even worse: there is no way to access C.

Answer (score 4):

***Generic types are erased at runtime.***

The runtime can't tell whether a `Money` object is `Money<Dollar>` or `Money<Franc>`. They all look like `Money` to it.

So what data does your `Money` objects actually have at runtime then, if not the currency? Well, only the `amount`. Only the values of `amount` can be compared because the information about whether it is `Dollar` or `Franc` is lost. And in this case, the amounts are both `4.0`, so they are considered equal as far as the runtime is concerned.

To make the test succeed, you could store an extra `Class<?>` field:

```
@Value
public class Money<C extends Currency> {

    private final Double amount;
    private final Class<C> currencyClass;
}
```

And you'll be forced to pass in a currency class when you create a `Money`:

```
new Money(4.0, Dollar.class)
```

Comment: So the type parameter is only a hint which is evaluated and checked during compile time. What is the consequence to have only this "simple" types during runtime? Why isn't this relevant during runtime?

Comment: "So the type parameter is only a hint which is evaluated and checked during compile time." Yes. "Why isn't this relevant during runtime?" Well, it _is_ relevant. It's just a weakness of Java's generics. @jellobird

Comment: I think this weakness is grounded in the implementation of the language (and jvm) because the same problem occurs with Scala as well.